# Subclasses with same behaviour but different attributes for different inputs

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, python, inheritance, subclassing

Say I have two object types of the same interface `MyObj` (I am using python in this project so I will use the same for the explanation)

```py
class Foo(MyObj):
    a = [5, 10]

class Bar(MyObj):
    a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Now I have this other class to do something with `MyObj` objects. Doing this is almost exactly the same for both `Foo` and `Bar` type of objects. However, an intermediate step of this process requires different attributes for `Foo` and `Bar`

```py
class Thing:
    needed_func: Callable  # This function does something with the variable `a`

    def __init__(self, o: MyObj):
        """Initialization which is the same for Foo and Bar"""

    def do_the_thing():
        """steps to do the thing which is the same for both Foo and Bar"""
        # Here I need to use the `needed_func`

class ThingFoo(Thing):
    needed_func = func_for_foo # takes a 1D array as input

class ThingBar(Thing):
    needed_func = func_for_bar  # takes a 2D array as input
```

When I have the `Thing.do_the_thing` implementation, I only need the two line implementations of the `ThingFoo` and `ThingBar` implementations to work with `Foo` and `Bar` objects. Since I do not need to override the `__init__` in the subclasses, both `Thing`'s subclasses will accept any `MyObj`'s subclasses which is bad design.

How should I structure my code such that `ThingFoo` and `ThingBar` only accept the respective objects?

---

**TL;DR**

Obviously I can implement init functions in the subclasses as follows. I am asking it there is a better way?

```py
class ThingFoo(Thing):
    needed_func = func_for_foo # takes a 1D array as input

    def __init__(self, o: Foo):
        super().__init__(o)

class ThingBar(Thing):
    needed_func = func_for_bar  # takes a 2D array as input

    def __init__(self, o: Bar):
        super().__init__(o)
```

Comment: Are you looking for [generic types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics)?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using `o` instead of the standard `self` here?  I think it's highly advisable to stick to the norm unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: @JimmyJames My bad. I forgot the self. Corrected

Comment: I would like to know the reason for the down vote as well if possible. I was hoping the question was clear enough

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ A lot of perfectly good questions attract a downvote or two right after they are posted.  Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the `__init__` method *looks* the same for `ThingFoo` and `ThingBar`, doesn't mean that you should avoid writing them at all costs. DRYing your code only makes sense if the code has *duplicated functionality*, not similar appearance.

To make this point clear, let's rename your classes for a moment:

- `MyObj` -> `Vehicle`
- `Foo` -> `Car`
- `Bar` -> `Truck`
- `Thing` -> `Garage`
- `ThingFoo` -> `CarGarage`
- `ThingBar` -> `TruckGarage`

Theoretically, a `Garage` is able to work with any kind of `Vehicle`. But `CarGarage` and `TruckGarage` are meant to work with a specific type of `Vehicle` - `Car` and `Truck`, respectively. **This restriction should be reflected in the code**,

Assuming this analogy to be valid in your case, I would write:

```
class ThingFoo(Thing):
    needed_func = func_for_foo # takes a 1D array as input

    def __init__(self, o: Foo):
        if not isinstance(o, Foo):
            raise TypeError("o is not an instance of Foo")
        super().__init__(o)


class ThingBar(Thing):
    needed_func = func_for_bar  # takes a 2D array as input

    def __init__(self, o: Bar):
        if not isinstance(o, Bar):
            raise TypeError("o is not an instance of Bar")
        super().__init__(o)
```

Yes, the code in `ThingFoo.__init__` and `ThingBar.__init__` is apparently "duplicated", but it serves a purpose: it checks if the correct `Vehicle` has been put in the appropriate `Garage`. Generic things that `Garage`s do to `Vehicle`s are then delegated to the parent class through the `super().__init__` call.

Comment: This explanation is exactly what I was looking for. (An exception is not necessary in my case, I'll stick with the typing for `o` in the `__init__`)